# How to fill input file if I selected something

Tags: jquery, select, input, autocomplete

I am beginner and now I am only search and copy-paste programmer. Exacly I am elektrician and this what I try to write is my hobby.

Can you help me with form functionality. In table test i have to rows. I tested autocomplete function. It works!
But tell me how to add surneme to  surname input file if I select one of the name from select filed. I read something about hidden filed but this is not working in my case.

Php and mysql i understand, but javascript and ajax and jquery not so much.

Table have column id, name, surname.

I have html code:

```
 <html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'search.php'
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>surname</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input id="name"> </td> 
    <td><input id="surname"></td>
 <table>
</body>
</html>
```

And search.php .  I removed code responsible for connect to mysql.

```
<?php
    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
    $query = "SELECT id,  name FROM t_simpel WHERE name  LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY name ASC";

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data[]  = $row['name'] ;
            }   
        echo json_encode($data  ) ;  
        }
    $mysqli->close(); 
?>
```

I do not know how to add surname to input #surname filed when I select #name on select list.

**Edit:**

I tried [your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48957495/652669). It works, but not like i want.
I will try explain one more time what i want to write..
I create table with columns id, name, surname.
I want to create form wchich give me posibility add new row + remove row. This part of code i have and works fine. I took it from one of tutorial in internet. 
Now i want to create  some form wchich give me posibility to generate list (table).
This list should I have posibility to edit.
I see it like that:
I add new line and next in this new line I begin write first letter of  name and next from list I want to select one of person. Name and surname should be loaded to input filed and id in hidden input.
I selected inputs filed because I want to have posibility to edit this name and surname fileds.

And now when i try add more the name filed to select statemend - autocomplete is not working.

When i added your code - this add  value from surname filed to name filed.

Can you help me? Probably i ask you about ready solution, but I realy want to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`change`](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change) event to perform an action when the field is changed with AutoComplete. This will append the surname to the name that you selected from the completion menu.

```
$(function() {
  $("#name").autocomplete({
    source: 'search.php',
    change: function() {
      this.value = this.value + " " + $("#surname").val();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok, thx but I thing I have something wrong with search php, becouse i changed the code and function autocomplete is not working.

Comment: I found. Because i changed mysql connect data. autocomplete is working

Comment: One more question.  is Line  $data[]  = $row['name']  ok?;

Comment: This is what i have in programmer tool in chrome   ["test", "test1"]
0
:
"test"
1
:
"test1"

Comment: @luki Yes, that line is fine.

Comment: I don't know what's causing that, you have no `console.log()` statements in your JS.

Comment: Do you can explain me what means this line? this.value = this.value + " " + $("#surname").val();

Comment: `this.value` is the value of the input field. After the autocomplete, it contains the name that the user selected. `$("#surname").val()` is the value of the surname field. `+` performs string concatenation, so it combines the name and the surname with a space between them.

Comment: Ok, thx for help. Mayby tommorow I will have fresh mind. Nice weekend for you.